# Regarding title field in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Actually the js which i wrote there is expecting a json of this format

```js
[{
  "type": "My bharath",
  "Q1": 1230,
  "Q2": 571,
  "Q3": 166,
  "Q4": 2
}]
```

but we are sending json in this format

```js
[{
  "data": {
    "type": "My Bharath",
    "Q4' 2014": 4,
    "Q1' 2015": 4,
    "Q2' 2015": 508,
    "Q3' 2015": 0
  },
  "legends": {
    "Q1": "Q4' 2014",
    "Q2": "Q1' 2015",
    "Q3": "Q2' 2015",
    "Q4": "Q3' 2015"
  }
}]
```

```
"graphs" : [{
        "balloonText" : "[[category]] <br>[[title]]:[[value]]",
        "fillAlphas" : 0.8,
        "id" : "4",
        "lineAlpha" : 0.2,
        "title" : "9-12 Months",
        "type" : "column",
        "valueField" : "Q4"
    },{
        "balloonText" : "[[category]] <br>[[title]]:[[value]]",
        "fillAlphas" : 0.8,
        "id" : "3",
        "lineAlpha" : 0.2,
        "title" : "6-9 Months",
        "type" : "column",
        "valueField" : "Q3"
    }, {
        "balloonText" : "[[category]] <br>[[title]]:[[value]]",
        "fillAlphas" : 0.8,
        "id" : "2",
        "lineAlpha" : 0.2,
        "title" : "3-6 Months",
        "type" : "column",
        "valueField" : "Q2"
    }, {
        "balloonText" : "[[category]] <br>[[title]]:[[value]]",
        "fillAlphas" : 0.8,
        "id" : "1",
        "lineAlpha" : 0.2,
        "title" : "0-3 Months",
        "type" : "column",
        "valueField" : "Q1"
    } ],
```

First one is the type of json format i'm getting.
Second one is i'm triying to display graphs on basis of data obtained.

My problem is whenever the "valueField" : "Q4" then it must give title as "Q3' 2015" .
**so basically it must check the value field and give me title field by matching it with the json (Legends).**

In case of any query comment.

Comment: Ok then go for it. If not possible, then put your effort in the question

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dataLegends = [
{
    "data": {
        "type": "My Bharath",
        "Q4' 2014": 0,
        "Q1' 2015": 0,
        "Q2' 2015": 283,
        "Q3' 2015": 0
    },
    "legends": {
        "Q1": "Q4' 2014",
        "Q2": "Q1' 2015",
        "Q3": "Q2' 2015",
        "Q4": "Q3' 2015"
    }
}
];

var graphs = {"graphs" : [{
        "balloonText" : "[[category]] <br>[[title]]:[[value]]",
        "fillAlphas" : 0.8,
        "id" : "4",
        "lineAlpha" : 0.2,
        "title" : "9-12 Months",
        "type" : "column",
        "valueField" : "Q4"
    },{
        "balloonText" : "[[category]] <br>[[title]]:[[value]]",
        "fillAlphas" : 0.8,
        "id" : "3",
        "lineAlpha" : 0.2,
        "title" : "6-9 Months",
        "type" : "column",
        "valueField" : "Q3"
    }, {
        "balloonText" : "[[category]] <br>[[title]]:[[value]]",
        "fillAlphas" : 0.8,
        "id" : "2",
        "lineAlpha" : 0.2,
        "title" : "3-6 Months",
        "type" : "column",
        "valueField" : "Q2"
    }, {
        "balloonText" : "[[category]] <br>[[title]]:[[value]]",
        "fillAlphas" : 0.8,
        "id" : "1",
        "lineAlpha" : 0.2,
        "title" : "0-3 Months",
        "type" : "column",
        "valueField" : "Q1"
    } ]
};

window.log = function(msg) { document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += msg; };

// overwrite title field with lookup by valueField in legend hash
graphs.graphs.map(function(g) { g.title = dataLegends[0].legends[g.valueField]; });

// prove that we changed the title field
log(graphs.graphs.map(function(g) { return g.title; }));
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks... but i need the legend (like Q1' 2015 ) in the title field but can't hard code as it changes dynamically

Comment: What do you mean you need "the legend in the title field"? Do you want to overwrite the value for key `"title"` that already exists inside the graph hash with the value that was looked up in the legend hash?

Comment: when i plot the graphs then we display the title under graphs so for now (0-3months)... are shown but i require Q1' 2015 ... under the charts but can't hardcode...

Comment: i edited my question by adding some js part ...plz do watch it

Comment: is the format we are sending causing the problem as still i'm unable to get the graphs